# Angularjs : Unable to change url with $location.path

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to redirect my page to another url. But I am unable to do so using $location.path method.

```
var url = "http://" + $window.location.host + "/template/reservation.html";
$log.log(url);
$location.search({});
```

It works if I use this:-

```
$window.location.href = url;
```

But it doesn't work when I use `$location.path` in place of the above line, like this:-

```
$location.path(url);
```

It appends the url to the current url, which is of no use.
I want to use $location as it does not reloads the page unlike $window.

Comment: Please have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) also here is a [guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

Comment: you also can use $state.go(' '); read here http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting in solution, just in case someone else also got the same problem. I found the solution like this :-

i was unable to get the desired result by directly writing the below line :-

```
$location.path('/template/reservation.html');
```

or

```
$location.path("/template/reservation.html");
```

So I did the following changes in the js file :-

```
var app = angular.module( 'mainApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config( function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
  .when( '/', {
     templateUrl: '/login.html'
  })
  .when( '/reservationPage',{
     templateUrl: '/template/reservation.html'
  })
  .otherwise( {
     redirectTo: '/'
  });

});
```

and used $location.path as below :-

```
$location.path('/reservationPage');
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty normal, angular `$location` only works for relative URLs. 
For absolute ones, you'll have to use `$window` service on JS `window` object.

Comment: To complete this, you can have a look at `$location` [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location), you'll see that a `$location.asbUrl` method exists, but it's only a getter!

Answer (score 0):

[`$location.path()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#path) expects just the path part of the URL, not the full URL.

So try this:

```
$location.path("/template/reservation.html");
```